# Отказ в доступе к файлам в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree('E:\\test', 'D:\\')
```

Вот ошибка:

```
File "test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    shutil.copytree('E:\\test', 'D:\\')
  File "C:\Users\Назар\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 554, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
  File "C:\Users\Назар\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 455, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "C:\Users\Назар\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:\\'
```

В чем заключается проблема? Как решить? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) копирует **файл**. А Вы, если я не ошибаюсь, пытаетесь копировать **директорию**. *P. S.:* Кстати, при копировании директорий нужно не забывать конечный слеш (потому что бывают файлы и без расширений).

Comment: Я использовал shutil.copytree, это отпечатка

Comment: Но ведь в `Traceback` отчётливо видно, что Вы пытаетесь это делать с помощью `shutil.copy`... В файле `test2.py` на 3 строке. А функция `copytree` появилась в вопросе после Вашей [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1105569/timeline#history_6ce0ca55-ced5-4834-a551-b223a6ade51d). Не стоит так делать.

Comment: Извините, я всё исправил

Comment: А есть доступ к D:\ у вас? Попробуйте вручную туда что-то записать

Comment: Нет доступа, странно, раньше всё было хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй аргумент функции должен быть **каталогом**.

***Пример:***

```py
shutil.copytree('E:\\test', 'D:\\test')  # При том, что D:\test не существует
```

Описание функции [`shutil.copytree(src, dst)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree):

> Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at `src` to a directory
>   named `dst` and return the destination directory.

Comment: Ошибка, только другая: FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'D:\\python'

Comment: @Nazar Новая ошибка говорит сама за себя: `Невозможно создать файл, если он уже существует`. Если Вы удалите каталог (**!**) и файл в месте назначения и попробуете ещё раз, то всё должно получиться.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)) Всё работает!